# How to "tab" in textbox in Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I want to make a text-editor web-application for writing Thai poems. Thai poems look as follows:

```
    XXXXXXXXXX   XXXXX
XXXXXXX          XXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX        XXXXX
XXXXXX           XXXX
```

The second column of the poem must start in the same position. Is there a way to change the word-space property so that the next sentence always starts in the same position? Or is it better to just create a table and make the border invisible?

Comment: Will the text in left cross specified width? If yes, then should all the previous right side should also move and align or the left side text will be wrapped?

Comment: If Thai has monospaced fonts, you could dynamically adjust the number of spaces between words everytime the user adds a space.

Comment: @A.J It probably won't cross the specified width.

Comment: @spenibus Thai does have monospaced fonts but they look really bad.

Comment: A live preview would probably be the simplest. The only alternative I can think about is a dynamic input form masquerading as a single textbox. That would basically use one textbox per column and javascript would be used to jump around as if they were one.